# How to define default "TagPrefix" for custom controls

Tags: asp.net

I have a number of custom controls that I am trying to enable designer support for. The signature looks something like the following:

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:MyDropDownList runat=\"server\" CustomProp="123"></{0}:MyDropDownList>")]
public class MyDropDownList: DropDownList
{
   ... code here
}
```

This works fine, but when I drag a control onto the page from the toolbox, the TagPrefix that gets added is "cc1":

```
<%@ Register Assembly="DBMClientPortal.Controls" Namespace="DBMClientPortal.Controls"
    TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

Obviously it is somewhat irrelevant what that TagPrefix is... it works as it stands, but I figured I *must* be able to change it somehow and curiosity got the better of me...

Anyone know how to define what the TagPrefix will be set to when dragging a custom control onto a page in visual studio?

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks something like this:

```
[assembly:TagPrefix("MyControls","RequiredTextBox")]
```

and [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.tagprefixattribute.tagprefixattribute.aspx) some more info about it.

Comment: But when we adding [assembly:TagPrefix("MyControls","RequiredTextBox")] this control cannot add into toolbox. Error : There are no components in DLL that can be placed on toolbox

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the TagPrefix attribute is only a *suggestion* to Visual Studio and other designer tools. If the user already has your namespace registered to a different tag prefix then it is free to use that tag prefix. Also, if your suggested tag prefix is already in use and points to a different namespace, the Visual Studio will use an auto-generated tag prefix instead.

However, the odds of either one of those happening is fairly small if you choose a tag prefix that is based on your product's or company's name.